# Ruby hash by reference

Tags: ruby, pointers, hash

I want to have a single target and then have that target be modifiable in a hash.

```
target = [1,2,3]
hash = {1 => target, 2 => target}
```

Now, I want to be able to either a) change target and have the hash auto update or b) change the hash's 1 and have it automatically change hash's 2.  Neither work:

```
target = [6,7,8]
target
```

output:

```
{1=>[1, 2, 3], 2=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

Plan b:

```
hash[1] = [6,7,8]
```

output:

```
{1=>[6, 7, 8], 2=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

So I'm discerning that when you make a subhash an rvalue in a hash in Ruby, it's duping the subhash before setting the lvalue to equal it.  What I want is the for Ruby to not to do that.  Is this possible?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 7):

`target` is just a name, `[1,2,3]` is the object it is referring to. Arrays are mutable, so you can change them:

```
target = [1,2,3]
p hash = {1 => target, 2 => target} # =>{1=>[1, 2, 3], 2=>[1, 2, 3]}
target.replace([6,7,8])
p hash # =>{1=>[6, 7, 8], 2=>[6, 7, 8]}
```

Comment: ...or `target[0..-1] = [6,7,8]`.

Comment: but this implies that hash[1] and hash[2] occupy 2 distinct memory spaces.  my question is about memory efficiency,not "how do i replace 2 duplicative targets with one line of code"

Comment: @user1130176 no, it implies that `hash[1]`, `hash[2]`, and `target` all refer to the very same object. You could also write `hash[1].replace([6,7,8])` and the changes would be reflected by `hash[2]` and `target`. Your assumption that writing `{1=> target}` would duplicate the object `target` refers to, is wrong. Instead, the same object is being referenced from within hash.

Comment: @user1130176 You can compare the object_id's: `target.object_id;hash[1].object_id;hash[2].object_id.` They are the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should change the array itself, as already mentioned by @steenslag.

Here is just another example which also shows it wotking on a value of the `Hash`. You can try other methods from the [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html) class.

```
target = [1,2,3]
h = {a: target, b: target}
h #=> {:a=>[1, 2, 3], :b=>[1, 2, 3]}

[3,4,5].each do |e|
  target.shift
  target.push(e)
end
h #=> {:a=>[3, 4, 5], :b=>[3, 4, 5]}


[7,8,9].each do |e|
  h[:a].shift
  h[:a].push(e)
end

h #=> {:a=>[7, 8, 9], :b=>[7, 8, 9]}
```